# Amazon CloudWatch endpoints - CIDR BLOCK for OutBound Whitelisting

Tags: amazon-web-services

Any idea if possible to get the cidr block for the service endpoint

```
monitoring.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
```

The context is basically, instance is restricted to certain ip outbound, having said that service endpoint must also be whitelisted, since the endpoint is "service endpoint", is it possible to get the cidr of this endpoint to be added to outbound SG definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible, but you would have to get the endpoints' CIDRs by **filtering** the [AWS IP address ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#filter-json-file) for CloudWatch and your region.

But bear in mind that endpoints can have multiple CIDR ranges, thus you may find out that there are more CIDRs then you can place in a SG.